OpenSearch: Cancelled task with reason: heap usage exceeded
Have an OpenSearch index named my_html with the following mapping:
{
  "my_html": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "default_my_ngram"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "html_content"
        },
        "crawl_completed": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "date_optional_time"
        },
        "index_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "default_my_ngram"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "my_normalized_keyword"
        },
        "minimized_byte_size": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "original_byte_size": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "url": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "default_my_ngram"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "my_normalized_keyword"
        },
        "url_submitted": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "default_my_ngram"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "my_normalized_keyword"
        },
        "url_submitted_hash": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "store": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I am sending the following query to the cluster:
{
  "size": 10000,
  "_source": false,
  "stored_fields": "url_submitted_hash",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match_phrase": {
              "content.ngram": "Hello"
            }
          },
          {
            "match_phrase": {
              "content.ngram": "World"
            }
          },
          {
            "match_phrase": {
              "content.ngram": "Goodbye"
            }
          },
          {
            "match_phrase": {
              "content.ngram": "Story"
            }
          }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

While I am getting some results, I am also getting the following failures in the response:
{
  "took": 3981,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 300,
    "successful": 298,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 2,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "my_html",
        "node": "AOz4jZjPTP6aCKoCzCLK4g",
        "reason": {
          "type": "rejected_execution_exception",
          "reason": "cancelled task with reason: heap usage exceeded [634mb >= 38.4mb]"
        }
      },
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "my_html",
        "node": "AOz4jZjPTP6aCKoCzCLK4g",
        "reason": {
          "type": "rejected_execution_exception",
          "reason": "cancelled task with reason: heap usage exceeded [645.7mb >= 38.4mb]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
. . .

This error appears randomly so the query isn't apparently not always using the same amount of heap? Here is the jvm of that node:
"jvm": {
        "timestamp": 1725384222017,
        "uptime_in_millis": 1119230629,
        "mem": {
          "heap_used_in_bytes": 2353246688,
          "heap_used_percent": 28,
          "heap_committed_in_bytes": 8187281408,
          "heap_max_in_bytes": 8187281408,
          "non_heap_used_in_bytes": 508853184,
          "non_heap_committed_in_bytes": 516882432,
          "pools": {
            "young": {
              "used_in_bytes": 1707081728,
              "max_in_bytes": 0,
              "peak_used_in_bytes": 4907335680,
              "peak_max_in_bytes": 0,
              "last_gc_stats": {
                "used_in_bytes": 0,
                "max_in_bytes": 0,
                "usage_percent": -1
              }
            },
            "old": {
              "used_in_bytes": 633675264,
              "max_in_bytes": 8187281408,
              "peak_used_in_bytes": 6907823104,
              "peak_max_in_bytes": 8187281408,
              "last_gc_stats": {
                "used_in_bytes": 608272384,
                "max_in_bytes": 8187281408,
                "usage_percent": 7
              }
            },
            "survivor": {
              "used_in_bytes": 12489696,
              "max_in_bytes": 0,
              "peak_used_in_bytes": 616562688,
              "peak_max_in_bytes": 0,
              "last_gc_stats": {
                "used_in_bytes": 12489696,
                "max_in_bytes": 0,
                "usage_percent": -1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "threads": {
          "count": 278,
          "peak_count": 278
        },
        "gc": {
          "collectors": {
            "young": {
              "collection_count": 12144,
              "collection_time_in_millis": 1008431
            },
            "old": {
              "collection_count": 0,
              "collection_time_in_millis": 0
            }
          }
        },
        "buffer_pools": {
          "mapped": {
            "count": 4716,
            "used_in_bytes": 58081248997,
            "total_capacity_in_bytes": 58081248997
          },
          "direct": {
            "count": 284,
            "used_in_bytes": 6439270,
            "total_capacity_in_bytes": 6439268
          },
          "mapped - 'non-volatile memory'": {
            "count": 0,
            "used_in_bytes": 0,
            "total_capacity_in_bytes": 0
          }
        },
        "classes": {
          "current_loaded_count": 54918,
          "total_loaded_count": 55469,
          "total_unloaded_count": 551
        }
      }

Based on this info, I wouldn't expect to be getting this heap error based on the large jvm memory available to the data node. Any suggestions on where to look?
